# Vectors and Matrix Calculations

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I'm making a game engine currently and I have some questions related to math, it's not a "what's the result of X" but something more conceptual which I don't quite understand.

Objects in the game space are represented by one vector XYZ for position and one for scale.
Then using some formulas you can find in any tutorial about positioning, they'll tell you to generate a matrix representing the transformations (translation, rotation, scale) of this object, which I'll use to multiply with other matrices for viewing.

This is one of the things I've did because I've been told to do so, but I always wanted to ask:

1. Why is this done with matrices? From what I remember a Vector4 * Matrix4x4 will result in a Vector4, but given that I can store position and scale in a Vector4, isn't it easier and faster to work with Vector4s? (if possible, that is)
2. Regarding rotations, if I can store them in a Vector3 representating an arbitrary axis and a value T, can't I add/subtract rotations easily from another Vector3? Again in this example I always find some complex matrix formulas to use when multiplying two transformations (such as an object inside another object).

Comment: It's true that you can use an [axis-angle representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis–angle_representation) to store rotations. However, you can't just add/subtract them as such. How would you combine a $90^\circ$ rotation about X with a $90^\circ$ rotation about Y?